# What is the registration number of the 10,000th Airbus?

Tags: aircraft-registration

Recently, Airbus delivered its 10,000th aircraft (an A350 to Singapore Airlines). What is its registration number?

I understand the registration number is specific to the airline, and has nothing to do with the manufacturer.

[image: The plane / Source AFP]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The answer you are looking for is: 9V-SMF.

[image]
<sup>Current registration number: [9V-SMF](https://www.jetphotos.com/info/A350-054) ([source](http://australianaviation.com.au/2016/10/airbus-delivers-10000th-aircraft/))</sup>

Let's try to add some related details.

---

Aircraft can have multiple ID during their life, at least a preliminary ID to be used by the manufacturer prior to delivery to the customer, and then at least a national registry ID.

**Manufacturer pre-delivery ID**

Airbus aircraft final assembly line for the A350 is in France at Blagnac, a small city near Toulouse, with parts coming from [several countries](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fd/Transport_A380_en.svg/2000px-Transport_A380_en.svg.png). There are other [final assembly lines](https://www.airbus.com/aircraft/how-is-an-aircraft-built/final-assembly-and-tests.html), but none is for the A350.

The first test flights will therefore happen in France, well before delivery to the customer. The French registry delivers temporary IDs to Airbus, the same IDs being continuously reused on successive airframes. Airbus uses a lot of them.

In France temporary IDs start with letter W. This A350 has been registered **F-WZFD** until being delivered to Singapore Airlines:

[image]
<sup>The special 10,000th aircraft delivery logo on A350-900 MSN 54 with its temporary registration: F-WZFD ([source](http://australianaviation.com.au/2016/10/airbus-delivers-10000th-aircraft/))</sup>

This same number was previously used on other aircraft, e.g.this [A350 c/n 9](http://www.airport-data.com/aircraft/photo/001084238L.html) and will be reused on next pre-production or pre-delivery aircraft.

**Customer registration**

Singapore Airlines then requested an ID which was delivered by the Singaporean registry. This ID is [**9V-SMF**](https://www.jetphotos.com/info/A350-054):

This number was previously used for a [B747](http://www.airfleets.fr/ficheapp/plane-b747-24066.htm) at Singapore Airlines.

Comment: What's the meaning of the 54 beneath the temporary registration? Disambiguating the various aircraft to have used that temporary registration?

Comment: @gsnedders: It's the manufacturer serial number (MSN), or  construction number (c/n). This airframe should be the 54th of the A350 series, a list can be found [here](https://sites.google.com/site/a350xwbproduction/production-list).

Answer (score 0):

The MSN Number is the Airbus Manufacturen No. all parts of this Aircraft are connected to the MSN 10000. This Aircraft will be a A320 from MEA in 2020.
But the MSN 10003 A321ACFwill be delivered n September 2019 is a IB03.

Comment: I'm a bit confused... You're claiming that the 10,000th aircraft _will be_ delivered by Airbus in 2020? There are photos above (from around 2016) of the aircraft Airbus claims to be their 10,000th in posts dated 2016. Can you please provide some more details to explain what you mean, and, if possible, some references to support your claims?

Comment: Each Airbus type has a MSN series starting with 1, it sounds like you're talking about the 10,000th A320, not the 10,000th Airbus aircraft.