# Can a registration number be reused indefinitely?

Tags: aircraft-registration

[This answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/32434/3394) highlights the fact that some registration numbers can be reused (here F-WZFD as a temporary registration number for newly built aircraft and 9V-SMF for a commercial airliner). This made me wonder how many times registration numbers can be reused and the existing constraints to reuse a registration number.

- Is there a limit for the number of time a registration number can be reused?
- Is there a minimum time between the decommissioning of an aircraft and the reuse of its registration number?
- Are there registration number that cannot be reused?

I'm interested by all ICAO's member but if needed, the answer can be narrowed to the jurisdictions covered in the linked question, namely Singapore and Europe.

Comment: In what country?

Comment: @RonBeyer edited accordingly

Comment: Related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3533/can-you-re-register-a-de-registered-aircraft-with-the-same-n-number